# Recreate vintage 70s-90s photo with new DSRL

Tags: film, vintage

I ask for your advise in recreating those 70s-90s photographs like **this picture I took** from a printing whose author is Elizaveta Porodina (2023).

What is the technique used to create such a picture, do I need a Nikon F6 or other film camera? do I need a full frame camera? I only have a Nikon D3400 and would like to recreate those types of pictures.

[image]

Comment: What particular characteristics of this photo do you want to reproduce?

Comment: I am not sure, I don't know much about photography but at least the colors looks awesome.

Comment: So bright, saturated colors. You can do this in post processing for any camera.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with your current camera and, for example, Lightroom or other software such as Darktable.

---

You should take a look at the following points (I'm referring to Lightroom, it should work the same way in other programs) and edit them to your own taste:

- **Contrast**: Increase the contrast until you like it
- In addition, you can increase the value for "**White**" to overexpose bright areas of the image
- You can increase the value for "**Black**" slightly to achieve a washed-out black.
- If you want to make the adjustments using the **Tone Curve**, raise the lower part of the graph to wash out the dark areas and drag the upper part of the graph up-left to overexpose more bright areas

It should somehow look like this:

```
|            |
|           /
|         /
|       /
|     /
|_ _/
|_______________
```

- You can also increase the **saturation** a little or play with the **dynamic** slider until you like it.
- In **HSL** you can adjust the saturation, brightness and hue for individual colors.

---

The style in the photo seems mainly to come from the washed out blacks and high contrast/saturation.

Alternatively, Lightroom also comes with many presets that you can try out.
It is difficult to suggest exact settings based on the photo.
But you don't need any special hardware for this.

However, I would recommend taking the photos as RAW so that you have more leeway in post-production.

Comment: Yes, I always shoot in raw. Indeed, I have darktable I will experiment with it. There are so many options, looks like I had to study a career to fully understand it.